# permission denied when using rubyzip

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

I'm trying to figure out a way to zip files using rubyzip. I rolled back to version 0.9.9 because the new version didn't work. below is the code I'm trying to test it with

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip/zip'

folder = "/temp"
input_filenames = ['COKE.csv', 'GM.csv', 'GOOG.csv']

zipfile_name = "/archive.zip"

Zip::ZipFile.open(zipfile_name, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  input_filenames.each do |filename|
    # Two arguments:
    # - The name of the file as it will appear in the archive
    # - The original file, including the path to find it
    zipfile.add("archive", folder + '/' + filename)
  end
  zipfile.get_output_stream("myFile") { |os| os.write "myFile contains just this" }
end
```

I get an error though, Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /archive.zip20140716-17537-1t9f1pd. I guess this is something to do with disc permissions? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t try to put archive file in the root filesystem, since you don’t have rights to write there:

```
- zipfile_name = "/archive.zip"
+ zipfile_name = "/temp/archive.zip"
```

Hope it helps.